# How to connect an action to a value change in C++/Qt

Tags: c++, qt

I do have a question. I'm currently developing an app and this app is reporting the available space on a device.

The display is done in my `Window` class of my file `mainwindow.cpp`

```
void MainWindow::createInfoSection()
{
    uint64_t space;
    CreateInfoSection = new QWidget();
    CreateInfoSection->setFixedHeight(40);

    QGridLayout *CreateInfoLayout = new QGridLayout(CreateInfoSection);

    NbOfItemsLabel = new QLabel(tr("%1 Files").arg(m_device.getNbOfFiles()));

    space = m_device.getAvailableFreeSpaceInBytes();

    if(space < MEGABYTE)
        SpaceAvailLabel = new QLabel(tr("%1 KB Remaining").arg(space/KILOBYTE));
    else if (space < GIGABYTE)
        SpaceAvailLabel = new QLabel(tr("%1 MB Remaining").arg(space/MEGABYTE));
    else
        SpaceAvailLabel = new QLabel(tr("%1 GB Remaining").arg(space/GIGABYTE));

    CreateInfoLayout->addWidget(NbOfItemsLabel, 0,0);
    CreateInfoLayout->addWidget(SpaceAvailLabel, 0,1);
    CreateInfoLayout->setAlignment(Qt::AlignCenter);

}
```

And I had a second method to just update the section when I want

```
void MainWindow::RefreshInfoSection()
{
    uint64_t space;

    NbOfItemsLabel = new QLabel(tr("%1 Files").arg(m_device.getNbOfFiles()));

    space = m_device.getAvailableFreeSpaceInBytes();

    if(space < MEGABYTE)
        SpaceAvailLabel = new QLabel(tr("%1 KB Available").arg(space/KILOBYTE));
    else if (space < GIGABYTE)
        SpaceAvailLabel = new QLabel(tr("%1 MB Available").arg(space/MEGABYTE));
    else
        SpaceAvailLabel = new QLabel(tr("%1 GB Available").arg(space/GIGABYTE));
}
```

the space available is get from a method declared in another class that I'm accessing using m_device. `getAvailableFreeSpaceInBytes` is defined as below in my `mtp_wrapper` class (in mtp_wrapper.cpp)

```
uint64_t mtp_wrapper::getAvailableFreeSpaceInBytes() {
    return PulsDeviceMngr->device->storage->FreeSpaceInBytes;
}
```

The `PulsDeviceMngr` is a structure which contain multiple elements.

What I'm looking for is a way to detect the change/update the value of `FreeSpaceInBytes` and update the section defined in my `MainWindow` using `RefreshInfoSection` as `RefreshInfoSection` due have a way to update the section and `QLabel`.

I'm pretty sure that it can be done by `CONNECT/SLOT/SIGNAL`

Any idea/examples.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What is `m_device`? It is the responsibily of `m_device` to notify others of changes. If it is possible, add a signal `ChangeInBytes` to `m_device` and then connect interested parties to that signal using roughly the following:

```
connect(SIGNAL(m_device->ChangeInBytes), SLOT(interested_party->slot))
```

If you can't modify m_device, you should probably create a wrapper-class, checking for changes in an appropriate way.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot monitor a variable, you need either a setter for the variable, that as suggested, raise a signal, or some sort of pooling on the variable itself to detect changes but this may be overkill.